# Is it possible to filter Visual Studio's terminal output logs by date and time?

Tags: visual-studio, terminal, output

I noticed that I am limited to viewing previous terminal output logs on Visual studio to a certain point in time by scrolling. Is there a way to view all visual studio logs and filter them by certain time and date?